# Scale of control variable in ANCOVA

Tags: ancova, scales, controlling-for-a-variable

I am new to the field of ANCOVAs. I want to check if two groups differ in three quantitative variables. At the same time I would like to control for gender and diagnose (6 categories).

Is it possible, to run an ANCOVA with a categorial control variable? Furthermore: can I enter the three quantitative variables at once or do I have to check them seperately? If so: is there a need to correct the data with bonferroni correction?

Comment: 'diagnose' is a verb. From the role the word is playing in your sentence, I think you need a noun there. Would 'diagnosis' fit what your variable contains? If you have three different response variables, you may be looking at MANOVA. If they're close to independent it may be reasonable to look at them separately. As to whether you do a correction for multiple testing depends on how much you worry about type I errors as against type II errors. How you view this may also depend on your audience.